# Не работает svg анимация

Tags: css, svg

в анимации не отрабатывает fill-opacity.

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #7fc4fc;
}
 @keyframes trap_stroke {
    0% {
    fill-opacity: 0.62;
    }
   100% {
    fill-opacity: 0.22;
     }
}  
.circle {
 animation: trap_stroke 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <symbol id="point">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="9" cx="50" cy="50" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#D3000E"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#D3CF00"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="r"
           from="9"
           to="16" 
           dur="3s"
           begin="1s"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           fill="freeze" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#point"</use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обе анимации можно оставить в svg

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #7fc4fc;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <symbol id="point">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="9" cx="50" cy="50" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#D3000E"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#D3CF00"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="fill-opacity"
           from="0.62"
           to="0.22" 
           dur="3s"
           begin="1s"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           fill="freeze" />
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="r"
           from="9"
           to="16" 
           dur="3s"
           begin="1s"
           repeatCount="indefinite"
           fill="freeze" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#point"</use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а в состоянии можно указывать вот так from="url(#linear-gradient)"?

Comment: Всмысле в анимации? Нет, значение должно быть числовым

Comment: Да в анимации требуется градиент...

Comment: Если нужно анимировать градиент, вы можете точно также анимировать каждый элемент `<stop>` в градиенте